# Problems with instalation of Rapidminer Studio (version 9.6) due to Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, rapidminer, openjdk-8

I'm trying to install RapidMiner Studio and I'm having problems related with Java, running the installation file `RapidMiner-Studio.sh` in my terminal (OS Ubuntu 18.04). I think I have all the requirements to install RapidMiner. I found out I had to have Java 8 or OpenJDK 8, so I installed and configured as explained [here](https://community.rapidminer.com/discussion/32891/error-when-installing-rapidminer-stuidio-in-ubuntu-164). Also, from the same source's suggestions, I added this in the `.sh` file: `--add-modules=java.xml.bind` (after `eval \"$JAVA\"`). Like this:

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
eval \"$JAVA\" --add-modules=java.xml.bind $JVM_OPTIONS -cp \"${rmClasspath}\" com.rapidminer.launcher.GUILauncher \"$@\"
else
eval \"$JAVA\" --add-modules=java.xml.bind $JVM_OPTIONS -cp \"${rmClasspath}\" com.rapidminer.launcher.GUILauncher
fi
```

My OpenJDK version is this:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

So, the errors I got from the installation file (after doing `chmod +x RapidMiner-Studio.sh` and `./RapidMiner-Studio.sh`) are the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.rapidminer.launcher.JVMOptionBuilder
Unrecognized option: --add-modules=java.xml.bind
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

It's clear it doesn't recognize the added module `java.xml.bind`.

So without that added module in the .sh file, I removed it. And running, I got the following errors:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.rapidminer.launcher.JVMOptionBuilder
Error: Could not find or load main class com.rapidminer.launcher.GUILauncher
```

How can I solve this Java problem?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Your evals are both the same, what's the purpose of this .sh anyway? I don't remember that something like this was necessary. Also, it doesn't seem as like a Java problem, rather a configuration problem I'd say. Check the classpath.

Comment: .sh file is RapidMiner-Studio.sh

Comment: Ok, I did that to the classpath and it worked. Thank you, Christos!

Comment: I think it would have been useful to write a detailed answer and also mark it as right. It would help the rest of the community of RM that will face the same problem in the future. Cheers! Also, welcome to SO!

Comment: @ChristosKarapapas did that :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering my question. So, to solve this, I simply had to replace the original line `rmClasspath="${RAPIDMINER_HOME}"/lib/*` with `rmClasspath=./lib/*`. This wasn't about the Java, but really the shell script. I had defined `RAPIDMINER_HOME` previously and somehow itwasn't reconized in that if statement.